# How to set data before login and get it after log in, Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm developing a module in Magento 1.9. My module has form and to submit the form, the user needs to log in. After login, I wanna get data of the form which user submit before login.
I set:

```
Mage::getSingleton('module/session')->setFormData()
```

I get:

```
Mage::getSingleton('module/session')->getFormData()
```

But when I debug, after customer login, I get form data is null.
How can I set form data like above?

Comment: have u tried with 'core/session'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code for it:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setFormData() ;
```

You can retrieve data using below code:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormData();
```

Comment: Thank you, but with:
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setFormData() ;    
and
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormData() ;
and now it work fine for me.